# How can I retrieve the ex Exception object from session state and display the Message property of the exception?

Tags: asp.net, exception

```html
ERROR.ASPX.CS page 

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace XEx21HandleErrors
{
    public partial class Error : System.Web.UI.Page
    {    
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  

            lblError.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
ERROR.ASPX


<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Error.aspx.cs" Inherits="XEx21HandleErrors.Error" %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="mainPlaceholder" runat="server">
    <h1 class="text-danger">An error has occurred</h1>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <p><asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server"></asp:Label></p>
    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnReturn" runat="server" Text="Return to Order Page" 
        PostBackUrl="~/Order.aspx" CssClass="btn btn-danger" />
</asp:Content>
```

```html
CONFIRMATION.ASPX.CS

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.Net.Mail;

namespace XEx21HandleErrors
{
    public partial class Confirmation : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var customer = (Customer)Session["Customer"];
            var date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString();
            var text = $"Thank you for your order, {customer.FirstName}! It will be shipped on {date}.";

            lblConfirm.Text = text;
            SendConfirmation(customer, text);
        }

        private void SendConfirmation(Customer customer, string body)
        {
          try
          {
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage("halloween@murach.com", customer.EmailAddress);
            msg.Subject = "Order Confirmation";
            msg.Body = body;

            string html = "<html><head><title>Order Confirmation</title></head>"
                        + "<body><h3>Thanks for your order!</h3>"
                        + "<p>" + body + "</p></body></html>";
            AlternateView view = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(html, null, "text/html");
            msg.AlternateViews.Add(view);

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("localhost");
            client.Send(msg);
            }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
                Session["Exception"] = ex; 
                Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx");
           }


        }
    }
}
```

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Order.aspx.cs" Inherits="XEx21HandleErrors.Order" %>

<asp:Content ID="mainContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="mainPlaceholder" runat="server">
    <div class="row"><%-- row 1 --%> 
        <div class="col-sm-8"><%-- product drop down and info column --%>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-6">Please select a product:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProducts" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Name" 
                        DataValueField="ProductID" CssClass="form-control">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                        ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:HalloweenConnection %>' 
                        SelectCommand="SELECT [ProductID], [Name], [ShortDescription], 
                        [LongDescription], [ImageFile], [UnitPrice] FROM [Products] 
                        ORDER BY [Name]">
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                </div>
            </div>   
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12"><h4><asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server"></asp:Label></h4></div></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12"><asp:Label ID="lblShortDescription" runat="server"></asp:Label></div></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12"><asp:Label ID="lblLongDescription" runat="server"></asp:Label></div></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12"><asp:Label ID="lblUnitPrice" runat="server"></asp:Label></div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"><%-- product image column --%>
            <asp:Image ID="imgProduct" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </div><%-- end of row 1 --%>
    <div class="row"><%-- row 2 --%>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2">Quantity:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" 
                        CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox></div>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" CssClass="text-danger"
                        runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtQuantity" Display="Dynamic" 
                        ErrorMessage="Quantity is a required field."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" CssClass="text-danger" 
                        ControlToValidate="txtQuantity" Display="Dynamic" 
                        ErrorMessage="Quantity must range from 1 to 500."
                        MaximumValue="500" MinimumValue="1" Type="Integer"></asp:RangeValidator></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add to Cart" 
                        onclick="btnAdd_Click" CssClass="btn" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnCart" runat="server" Text="Go to Cart" 
                        PostBackUrl="~/Cart.aspx" CausesValidation="False" CssClass="btn" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnCheckOut" runat="server" Text="Check Out" 
                        PostBackUrl="~/CheckOut1.aspx" CausesValidation="False" CssClass="btn" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><%-- end of row 2 --%>
</asp:Content>
```

Hello Everyone,

I am working on an application in which I want to display an exception error message when a user enters a email like this: **email** inside of the email textbox, but the problem that I am having is I am confused about how I can retrieve the **ex Exception object** from  session state and display the Message property of the exception in the label on the Error page. Here are some of my web application pages. I am trying to do this in the Error.aspx.cs (or code behind file). Do anyone think they can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use try catch in those pages/events.

```
try {
        //Do stuffs here such as pageload, click events and so on...
    }
catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Session["ErrorMsg"] = ex.Message;
        Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx");
    }
```

In Error.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblError.Text = Session["ErrorMsg"] == null ? "" : Session["ErrorMsg"].ToString();
        }
```